# 'Symbolic Math Toolbox' functions exist in MATLAB but not in the documentation

Tags: matlab

This problem may seem a bit weird; please bear with me.

When I try to access any function in the 'Symbolic Math Toolbox' in MATLAB, such as `help ztrans` or `help laplace`, I get the following kind of message

```
ztrans not found.

Use the Help browser Search tab to search the documentation, or
type "help help" for help command options, such as help for methods.
```

However, the toolbox seems to be installed when I try the `ver` or `pathtool` command.

Moreover, when I try some simple code such as:

```
>> syms k x
>> f = sin(k);
>> ztrans(f, k, x)
```

the code works fine and on trying the `help` command again, they seem to work fine as well. However, the problem again arises when I close and reopen MATLAB.

I found a few instances of other users facing similar problems on the Mathworks portal, but none of them seemed to provide any concrete solutions. Some of them seem to blame it on MATLAB hashing the tollbox incorrectly, so I tried the `rehash toolbox` command as well, but had no luck.

I'm not sure if this problem is just for this particular toolbox or not, but the other toolboxes I use at least seem to work fine.

**EDIT-I**

I also realised that the documentation is always available when I take `Help --> Product Help` from the menu-bar, though it is not available in the function browser even after I try the sample code.

**EDIT-II**

```
>> license('checkout','Symbolic_Toolbox')
```

gives me

```
ans =

     1
```

I'm not working on a student license either.

Comment: Sounds like there is something wrong with your MATLAB installation...

Comment: @AndrewMao: That's possible, I guess. Would there be any way to check the integrity of the installation?

Comment: The same issue here but I doubt corrupted installation: I have the Matlab Student version 2012a installed, the commandline help not working but commands do work.

Comment: Hey, is this the issue: you can execute all commands in the Matlab Symbolic toolbox but you cannot get the commandline help working? If it is, I suggest to clarify the question -- it looks that the commands do exist.

Comment: What do you mean by this *"the problem again arises when I close and reopen MATLAB"*?

Comment: @hhh: Once I use one of the commands appropriately, by say, using the example above, the help begins to work as expected. However this reverts to the initial state once I close and reopen MATLAB.

Comment: Hey! It is precisely the same issue here -- this must be some path issue.

Comment: @hhh: Maybe so. Weird thing is that I've had the same issue on two separate systems running two different versions. :|

Comment: Perhaps this is a "feature", not a bug...just run a command first and then help.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a license issue. Try to get further information with:

```
license('inuse')
```

If you have a Student version, some functions cannot be executed.

```
istudent
```

In case that you are in an office/university, and you have floating licenses. Be sure to check-out all the licenses before running your code.

```
license('checkout','toolbox_name')
```

Comment: Sorry, I had thought of that but I had forgotten to put it in my question. That didn't seem to be the issue however. I've updated my post to reflect that.

Comment: If you are a student, how can you get the Symbolic Math Toolbox commands working or try that they are working?

Comment: Do you have any local function or variable with the name 'ztrans'? Or, do you modify the paths of Matlab in any way?